# Couldn't Run the Emulator on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I couldn't run emulator on Android studio.

It says,

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware
>   acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and
>   usable. CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

But I already installed `intel HAX` and also enabled Hyper V from BIOS

I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro

Answer (score 0):

Check in Android SDK manager if the Intel x86 packages are properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing and opening your android studio so that android studio can detect installed intel HAXM.
Check whether you have the right version or of intel HAXM compatible to your android sdk. Also check whether you have installed 32 bit intel HAXM or 64 bit, as you required 32 bit.

More importantly, enable hardware virtualization technology extensions in BIOS.

It can be found under ‘Advanced Chipset settings’ in AWARD BIOS. Normally these vt-x/amd-v extension settings will be available in advanced settings in most of the motherboards.

After you have changed the settings to disable or enable, it’s recommended to shutdown the computer for minimum 10 seconds and restart it (Cold Restart) to take effect. Latest motherboards automatically detect these type of changes and do the cold restart. Whenever I change VT setting in my motherboard, it delays the restart automatically.

Comment: I tried it with several times.But didn't work. I intalled 32 bit from Android SDK

Comment: try re-installing intelHAXM from the right folder as mentioned by @JulianF.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run 
{SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe ?

Comment: Yes I run it. It says Hyper V is turned off. But Hyper V is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download) instead of built-in emulator, it's much faster and has a lot of nice features.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution

Goto Control Panel and in windows and feature untick all Hyper-V related content.

Then restart the machine and enable Hyper-V and install intel HAX "intelhaxm.exe" inside the AppData->Local->Temp folder in C Particition in Windows